# Формообразование и постоянные признаки

Tags: морфология

Слова принадлежат к частям речи, каждое слово имеет различные формы. При изменении слова по непостоянным признакам (части речи) принадлежность слова к части речи не меняется, остается тот же и лексический смысл. При изменении постоянных признаков может поменяться лексическое значение / часть речи? Правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем.Словоформа образуется при изменении непостоянных признаков, а вот постоянные не меняются, но нельзя сказать, что при изменении их поменяется часть речи. У существительных постоянные признаки -  одушевленность, собственное или нарицательное, склонение, род. У слова стол нельзя поменять род, склонение, одушевлённость и то, что оно нарицательное(если не назовёте город Стол), потому и называются постоянными, что у этого слова они всегда.
 А вот форма числа и падежа может меняться: столы, столом, о столе.

Числительные. Постоянные простое-составное, количественное-порядковое-собирательное. Это неизменно, а вот род(один, одна), число(один, одни), падеж (второй, второго, вторых; пять, пяти, о пяти) меняем.

Меняется часть речи при изменении значения: существительное означает предмет, глагол - действие, прилагательное - признак, наречие - признак действия и признак признака.